# Bootstrap badge don't always appear in Safari

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, safari

I have a tool that has 3 tabs and some counters on each tab.  The title of the tab is supposed to have a badge that shows a total of all counters on that tab.  If the total is 0, it shouldn't show any badge.

This all works fine in Chrome and Firefox, but in Safari (both on OS X and iOS) I get some very strange behavior that I can't seem to debug.

I have a badge with some very simple code:

```
<li role="presentation">
    <a href="#AB-bulk" aria-controls="AB-bulk" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" class="climb_type_nav">
        Auto-Belay       
        <span class="badge" id="AB-badge"></span>
    </a>
</li>
```

And some javascript to (re)set the html contents of the badge span:

```
// reset badge counts
$.each($('.climb_type_nav').find('.badge'), function (i, x) {
    $(x).empty();
});

// get counts per climb type
$.each($('.input-number'), function (i, x) {
    var climbs = parseInt(x.value, 10);
    if (climbs > 0) {
        var shortName = x.getAttribute('climb_type_short_name');

        if (!ct[shortName]) {
            ct[shortName] = 0;
        }
        ct[shortName] += climbs;
    }
});

// set badge counts
$.each(ct, function (shortName, count) {
    $('#' + shortName + '-badge').html('<b>' + count + '</b>');
});
```

To replicate the behavior in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ajLxsLc2/3/:

1. Click the plus sign to update the counter, or just manually type in a number and click off of the input -- You'll see the badge appear on the first tab
2. Click the minus sign to get the count back to 0 -- You'll see the badge disappear
3. Click the plus sign again to update the counter -- this time the badge will NOT appear in Safari
4. To get the badge to appear, either click on another tab or hover over the tab you're on

I've confirmed that the HTML value is being set inside the badge's span, it's just not showing up when in Safari for some reason.  Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a funny issue. I noticed the badge appears on mouse over, so this seems to fix it:

```
    // set badge counts
    $.each(ct, function (shortName, count) {
        $('#' + shortName + '-badge')
            .html('<b>' + count + '</b>')
            .parent().focus().blur();
    });
```

Take a look [at this updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ajLxsLc2/16/)

Comment: That seems to do the trick, thanks! Any idea _why_ it behaves this way?  Is it a bug in Safari or in my code somewhere?

Comment: I think it's a bug. This looks related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10534136/webkit-render-bug-for-dynamic-content. If you toggle any CSS property on the element via web inspector, you'll see it re-render itself correctly. That's probably why the method mentioned here works. It triggers the browser to re-render the element.

Comment: @flyingL123 yeah, that's what I was going for, triggering a re-render. Weird safari bug for sure.

Comment: @smenzer there's a lot going on there, but there's no issue that I see with that part of your code.

Comment: Thanks to both of you - really appreciate it!

Comment: @Ted - I found an issue with this solution.  In my actual project, I have about 8 of these entries per tab and it runs on a mobile device, which means you have to scroll.  If you have scrolled down (so the tabs are out of view), when you hit the plus/minus button, you get scrolled back up to the top of the page, which isn't ideal (you can't hit the + or - buttons multiple times in a row).  Any thoughts on how to work around that?

Comment: I tried `.parent().attr('disabled', true).removeAttr('disabled');` instead and it seems to work alright.  Any issues with this approach?