# Bootstrap Badge Broken in Safari

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, safari

I have a bootstrap badge that I've placed with a circular button. It works in my testing browsers (1) except for Safari in which it is clipped along the path of the rounded button edges.

[image]

CSS:

```
.toggler_btn {
position: fixed;         bottom: 0px;
right: 0px;              width:30px;
height:30px;             margin:1% 1% 2% 1%;
background-color: #000;  border-radius: 25px;
border:none;             }
```

HTML

```
<button type="button" class="toggler_btn" onclick="someJS()">
<img src="/img/chat.svg"><span class="badge">5</span>
</button>
```

Other questions on SO like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29969276/bootstrap-badge-dont-always-appear-in-safari) one address the badge being gone completely, but that answer doesn't solve my issue here.

*(1) Browsers used: Safari 9.1, Firefox 46, Opera 36, Chrome 50*